# Arduino port not discovered with bootloader / Did I fry my board?

Tags: power, usb, bootloader, uploading, arduino-nano-ble

I have a Arduino Nano 33 BLE that I've been using for a while. I usually upload new programs to the board through USB with the board in a bootloader loop. The other day this stopped working. The board can successfully be put in the bootloader (slow pulsing light), however it does not appear as a TTY device on my computer. The last program I put on my device still works, and successfully outputs serial output (and I can even connect to the bluetooth module).

This leads me to believe my board is working, though I don't understand why I cannot upload via the bootloader. Interestingly the bootloader running makes the board pretty hot (hotter than my program running, is it in an infinite loop or something?).

I thought the bootloader might've been corrupted, so I re-uploaded the board's bootloader via a raspberry pi over OpenOCD (it's possible I did this incorrectly?). Now the device remains in the bootloader no matter what.

I'm wondering if it's possible I fried just the USB part of my board? is that likely? I did hook up the board to a wall adapter that is rated 12V @ 1.5A. The issue seemed to occur after this. Is the board able to handle 1.5A? Do I need to use an additional circuit to properly power the board off of this power adapter?

Comment: So I cannot even attempt to upload it, as the board is not available for selection. A `ls /dev/tty.*` results in no devices.

Comment: If you put that 12V to Vin pin, it should be fine, to any other pin it means death.

Comment: @KIIV thanks! that's what I expected, I didn't see a max current for that pin, and assumed that shouldn't be a problem (it should just draw the amount it needs, no?)

Comment: Yes, I did see that, the detail data sheet says the Vin feeds into a 3.3V power which has a max current of 1A. Is it possible I messed something up there?

I have a new board on the way, my bigger concern is not also bricking that board, if I have indeed bricked my current board.

Comment: I'd expect smoke to appear if an Arduino gets fried with 12V and that should most likely have killed the entire controller.

Comment: Ya that's what I was thinking as well -- can anything explain the behavior I'm seeing then?

Comment: You can try to program it via an ISP programmer (for example using another Arduino). You can also reflash the bootloader that way. If the ISP programming fails, then your controller is dead.

Comment: Would that be any different than flashing a bootloader via OpenOCD?

Comment: I see `Input Voltage (limit)  21V`. Flashing over SWT is 'ISP'

Comment: you say "The last program I put on my device still works, and successfully outputs serial output". how it there is no port?

Comment: Over the TX and RX lines I can get serial output, but the on-board USB does not show up as a port

Comment: is the USB cable 'power only'?

Comment: It is not, same cable worked previously with the same board (I've tried other cables as well). I think I screwed up the bootloader now, probably used OpenOCD incorrectly. I have a BMP on the way. Maybe I can revive it that way. At this point it's to satisfy my curiosity